# Tkinter Label()'s text doesn't show up

Tags: python, tkinter, text, label

I am a beginner, when I am working on Tkinter with the given code, the text does not show in label. It's always a whole white screen. What should I do? My versions are updated.

```py
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("Python Tkinter")
window.minsize(width=500, height=300)

# label
my_label = tkinter.Label(text="this is a label", font=('Arial', 30, "bold"))
my_label.pack()

my_label.config(bg="black", fg="white")

window.mainloop()
```

I expected the text to show up.

Comment: ["Python - Tkinter Label This widget implements a display box where you can place text or images. The text displayed by this widget can be updated at any time you want."](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_label.htm) The code works as expected. You should edit the question and describe what you want to achieve so that it's clear how this differs from your expectations.